# Numbering commutative diagrams

Tags: numbering, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

Is there a nice way to number commutative diagrams (like equations) ? When using tikz-cd I put a figure environment around it, and then there is no number anywhere. I can also use

```
\begin{align}
\xymatrix{Some diagram}
\end{align}
```

but then the number is not placed nicely corresponding to the middle of the diagram.

Comment: wrap it in a  `gathered` env. I would not use `figure` for a `tikzcd` env, it is a math construction and should thus have a math eq number.

Comment: You can put a `tikzcd` environment in an equation.

Comment: Just for the record: *don't* use `align` for single line displays (and `\xymatrix` counts for a single line).

Comment: the number in a figure environment comes from `\caption{...}` so if you add some text for the  diagram in `\caption` it will b enumbered

Comment: Do you want them to share numbers with equations, or have their own set of numbers?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I would like to know how to do both.

Comment: @egreg Would you then also recommend using \begin{equation} in general instead of \begin{align}?

Comment: @B.Pasternak Definitely so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think you need a `figure` environment to use a `tikzcd` environment, that is not the case. In fact, one of the first things written in the introduction of the `tikz-cd` manual is

> Everything inside `{tikzcd}` is typeset in math mode, but you will probably want to use it inside an
>   `{equation}` environment or `\[ ... \]`, so that the diagram is placed on a new line and centered.

Hence, using a random example from the manual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow{d} \arrow{r}[near start]{\phi}[near end]{\psi}
& B \arrow[red]{d}{\xi} \\
C \arrow[red]{r}[blue]{\eta}
& D
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is in response to the OP's request to be ale to designate  a different set of numbers and label style to commutative diagrams.

It uses my `numberedblock` package that was intended to numbering code blocks, but used here for commutative diagrams.  It has a labeling/referencing system, and the tag location and appearance can be customized.

Unfortunately, this solution is a little inconvenient, because I cannot stick the `tikzcd` environment in directly as the argument to a `\numblock`.  SO I have to put it first in a temporary box and then apply the `\numblock` to the box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{numberedblock,lipsum}
\setlength\blockindent{0in}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\setbox0=\hbox{\begin{tikzcd}
R \arrow{r}{\phi} \arrow[swap]{d}{\chi} & S \arrow{d}{\Psi} \\
R/I \arrow{ur}{\psi} \arrow{r}{\Phi} & T
\end{tikzcd}}
\numblock{\nblabel{cdA}\makebox[\textwidth]{\box0}}

\lipsum[4]

\setbox0=\hbox{\begin{tikzcd}
R \arrow{r}{\phi} \arrow[swap]{d}{\chi} & S \arrow{d}{\Psi} \\
blah blah R/I \arrow{ur}{\psi} \arrow{r}{\Phi} & T (blah-blah wider)
\end{tikzcd}}
\numblock{\nblabel{cdB}\makebox[\textwidth]{\box0}}

In commutative diagrams \ref{cdA} and \ref{cdB}, we see\ldots
\end{document}
```

[image]